# Best Way of Checking a String has one of Many Values in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm just in the middle of some Perl code and I found myself writing the monstrosity of a line of code shown below. Perl being so full of great little shortcuts, there just has to be a better way than this right?

So - is there a better way to do this:

```
unless($config->{'case_transform'} eq 'NONE' || 
       $config->{'case_transform'} eq 'UPPER' ||
       $config->{'case_transform'} eq 'LOWER' ||
       $config->{'case_transform'} eq 'CAPITAL' ||
       $config->{'case_transform'} eq 'RANDOM')
{
    $config->{'case_transform'} = 'NONE';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also available is the "[Smart Match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail)" operator `~~`.

```
use 5.010;

$config->{'case_transform'} = 'NONE' 
    unless $config->{'case_transform'} ~~
        ( 'NONE', 'UPPER', 'LOWER', 'CAPITAL', 'RANDOM' );
```

Answer (score 6):

```
my %good_value = map { $_ => 1 } qw( NONE UPPER LOWER CAPITAL RANDOM );

unless $good_value{$config->{case_transform}) {
    $config->{case_transform} = 'NONE';
}
```

Comment: If you used `map {$_ => $_}` you could replace the test/assignment with `$config->{case_transform} = $good_value{$config->{case_transform}} || 'NONE'`.  I'll leave it up to personal taste as to whether that's actually an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

```
unless ($config->{'case_transform'} =~ /^(NONE|UPPER|LOWER|CAPITAL|RANDOM)$/)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: A regex solution is easy to extend to cases where the input has leading/trailing whitespace or to case-insensitive matches.

Comment: ... and now you have two problems :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$config->{'case_transform'} = 'NONE' unless $config->{'case_transform'} =~ /^(?:UPPER|LOWER|CAPITAL|RANDOM)$/;
```